# Handling data across forms in java and working with multiple forms

Tags: java, forms, user-interface

I am trying to make a small stat based game in java but struggling how to use multiple forms along with my 'hero' class.

I have 5 classes so far MainMenu,PlayerCreationscreen,GameWindow, Person, Statgame.

In the statgame class it makes a main menu and a person but I don't know where to go from there.

```
public class StatGame {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @return 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mainMenu main = new mainMenu();
        Person hero = new Person();
    }
}
```

thats the code for the stat game which makes the main menu and the hero.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    if(command.equals("New")){
        playerCreationWindow playerMakeWindow = new playerCreationWindow();
        this.setVisible(false);
```

This is the code that happens on the main menu when I click new but after that I cannot use my person I made without remaking it in the other classes so it loses anything I do to it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could try doing is to pass the Person object into your other classes either through the constructor or by using a setter.